# why are host and hostile lookalike while they are of different meanings?

Tags: differences

My friend just asked me this today.

What should I tell him?

Are these words somehow related or were they related in the past and not anymore now?

Comment: @JRodge01 Reads like an answer to me.

Comment: @DJClayworth Made it an answer.  Links are hard to format on mobile :(

Comment: The incorrect assumption here is that words with some combination of identical letters will always be related. Sometimes they will, sometimes they won't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

English is a mishmash of different languages, meaning a lot of words may look the same but aren't from the same source language. Hostile comes from the Latin word ["hostis"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hostis#Latin) meaning enemy. "Host" comes from the French word ["hoste"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hoste#Middle_French)

Comment: Wiktionary is not a very extensive resource. For language roots a better resource is etymonline, where it shows that [host and hostile are cognate](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*ghos-ti-) along with guest, hospital, hotel, and hostage but not ghost. You should probably mention this, and also semantic drift in your answer.

Comment: +1 It's still the right answer. The vagaries of history, politics, culture, and usage over the thousand years that separate Latin and French account for all the meaning differences.